# I want to change all shape borders in slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

```
Dim oSh As Shape

For i =1 To 5
```

I gave here For loop to go and find each shape

```
With oSh
.Fill.Visible = False
.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Set oSh = Nothing
End With
Next i
```

But seems like does not work properly

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, not speculative advice. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or super User.

Comment: I think you messed up the code area in your post, also if you could give a sample of how your data looks like it would help to answer the question

Comment: I want to change all shape boxes border line color and roundness at once, in all shapes inside one slide

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work but you could try changing these properties on a range of cells like range("A1:B5")

Comment: Also your code is incorrect as oSh is never assigned to anything

Comment: It works fines without for loops. And there is no range, it is in pp

Comment: My bad I thought this was in excel, but how is your for loop selecting different shapes then? Usually I would assume you would have to go through the shape collection and pick the shapes you want, but I dont see where you choose a shape in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
With oSh
.Fill.Visible = False
.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Set oSh = Nothing
End With
```

To this, assuming that you want to work with the currently selected slide or slides:

```
Sub ChangeTheShapes()
' Make sure you select one or more
' slides (in the thumbnail pane or slide sorter)
' before running this.

    Dim osh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide
    
    ' in case a shape doesn't have a fill
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For Each oSl In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
        For Each osh In oSl.Shapes
            With osh
              .Fill.Visible = False
              .Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End With
        Next   ' Shape
    Next 'slide
    
End Sub
```

You can also delete anything you've done with the variable i since you're not using it for anything.

Comment: It gives error on Selection - Method or data member not found. I have already selected some shapes on slide

Comment: Sorry ... my bad.  Aircode!  See edited version above.  Tested, working.

Comment: Rindberg can you send me your tested working file?

Comment: I tested the code in a file, copy/pasted it here, then deleted the file. But see the latest version above; I've turned it into a stand-alone subroutine.